# System.RuntimeType doesn't contain a definition for Declared Properties

Tags: c#, .net, rest, xamarin.android, json.net

I am trying to Deserialize Json string to object in debug mode its working fine but at release mode throwing error such that System.RuntimeType doesn't contain a definition for Declared Properties...

Any Help Would Be Appreciated

```
public T DeserializeJSon<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        dynamic dT = typeof(T);

        if (dT.Name.EndsWith("List"))
            dT = dT.DeclaredProperties[0].PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];

        DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat(DateTimeFormat),
            UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true
        };
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
        stream.Dispose();

        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `dyanmic` at all, `typeof(T)` will *allways*  return an instance of `System.Type` so you should use type instead of `dynamic`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Can you please more specific i tried like this Type dT = typeof(T); but DeclaredProperties is an extension method which is giving error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DeclaredProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.typeinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) is a member of `System.TypeInfo`, not of `System.Type` and least of all `dyanmic`.

Thus simply write this instead:

```
Type dt = typeof(T);
if (dT.Name.EndsWith("List"))
    dT = dT.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.First().PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
```

I strongly recommend not to use `dyanmic` unless you really need it (which isn´t the case here). `Dynamic` will only shift the actual error (in your case access to a member that doesn´t exist) to runtime instead of to the compiler which makes it harder to find errors. Another reason here is that you already *know* the runtime-type of the expression `typeof(T)`, which is *allways* `System.Type`. Why should you want to hide this information by using `dynamic`?

Comment: Thanks A Ton @HimBromBeere that did the work for me.Thanks again for giving me the clear understanding about dyanmic